# How to render stateHook result from the function call in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the result of stateHook and render it properly

```
//import React from 'react';
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {DashboardLayout} from '../components/Layout';

const ProjectsPage = () => {

    function GetCount() {
        const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

        useEffect(() => {
            document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
                <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
                    Click me
                </button>
            </div>


        );
    }

    return (
        <DashboardLayout>
            <h2>Projects Page {GetCount}</h2>
        </DashboardLayout>
    )
}

export default ProjectsPage;
```

While rendering a function call in ReactJS it throws this error

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
    at h2
    at div
    at section
    at main
    at div
    at div
    at main
    at div
    at BodyWrapper (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:210:3)
    at DashboardLayout (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:338:3)
    at ProjectsPage
    at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:39794:29)
    at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:39996:29)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:39429:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:39049:35)
    at Routes
    at App
```

And the UI remains blank,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem the error message is referring to is here:

```
<h2>Projects Page {GetCount}</h2>
```

`GetCount` is a function (specifically, a component function). You're using it (not calling it) there. You want to use the component, like so:

```
<h2>Projects Page <GetCount/></h2>
```

I'd also suggest adding the missing dependency on the `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
}, [count]);
// ^^^^^^^
```

You don't absolutely need it if `count` is the only state item and the component has no properties, but it's best practice to list the effect's dependencies so it isn't called too often.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to render:

```
 <DashboardLayout>
            <h2>Projects Page {GetCount}</h2>
  </DashboardLayout>
```

However, `GetCount` is a function, hence:

> Functions are not valid as a React child.

What you should do is:

```
 <DashboardLayout>
            <h2>Projects Page</h2>
            <GetCount />
  </DashboardLayout>
```